# MacBook not recognizing Wireless N USB Adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, usb, hardware

I have an aluminum unibody (2008). I recently upgraded RAM & downloaded all software to get my baby up to date. THEN the wifi card died. I tried to fix that myself but thanks to Apple's almost spot-welded screws, I had to change directions. I got the usb adapter's drivers installed & when I inserted the adapter, I got nothing. NOTHING. Can someone please help this old lady? I just paid $35 to the local computer guy to remove a stripped screw. I'm trying really hard to not have to see him ever again. All I want is to use my MacBook again & throw this PC back in the corner.

HELP!!

Answer (score -1):

It might be an alteration in the USB ports. Try checking them out first.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what that means. :/